# How to allow access to friends of friends except for a certain friend

Tags: facebook

I want to allow friends of friends to see my wall posts. However there is a certain friend who I have that I want to block access to for his friends. I want to block his friends without blocking him. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know this isn't possible to do without blocking the friend also.